Kotlin Multiplatform + Jetpack Navigation + Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1 Patch 1 issues
I've started moving one of my older project (Java) to the KMP setup, my goal was to just move around the structure to KMP and slowly import Kotlin code from the shared folder into the androidApp.
I ran into an issue with the original Jetpack Navigation (without Compose) and the SafeArgs generator:
this one
I've added this:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        val nav_version = "2.7.7"
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
    }
}

to the top-level build.gradle, although I'm not sure it's the right place to be.
It properly generates the NavDirections into the
build/generated/source/navigation-args/flavor directory
At this point:

Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1 Patch 1 doesn't pick it up and complains about missing XXXDirections
But I can compile and run it on the emulator
with or without the top level androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin doesn't seem to make a difference
Restarting AS works (finds the generated class), syncing Gradle breaks it again

Could be an Android Studio only error, since compiling works fine.
If tried to manually add the generated folder to the java sourcesets:
 sourceSets {
        ...
        getByName("gms") {
            java.srcDirs(
                "build/generated/source/navigation-args/gms"
            )
        }
        ...
 }


which doesn't make a difference.
Any hints on how I can fix this or where the navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin is supposed to go ? Or this plugin doesn't work with the KMP project structure ?

You could try moving away from the navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin and try use the Compose Navigation library found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.androidx.navigation/navigation-compose-uikitarm64. As of version 2.8.0-alpha05 (which in this case you'll need to use 2.8.0-alpha08 or higher as not all versions have been added to Maven) you can use Type Safety with navigation which allows a different/similar method of strongly passing arguments when navigating.
I will not explain that in full detail here but as a start you could follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-compose-meet-type-safety-e081fb3cf2f8
As a side note, I found plugins with and generated code with KMP can sometimes be problematic with different target, rapidly changing versions of libraries and stability. I try hard to keep them to a minimum.

Is the Compose Navigation library viable for non-compose projects ?

Ah my bad, missed the compose part. No its compose only as far as I am aware
